# REST Standard for changing SPA Model after fetched from REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, standards

Let's imagine. I have following data from database.

```
======================================
id    |  Title     |   parentId
======================================
100      Asia          NULL
--------------------------------------
101      India         100
--------------------------------------
102      Tamil Nadu    101
--------------------------------------
103      Chennai       102
--------------------------------------
104      Karnataka     101
--------------------------------------
105      Bengalaru     104
--------------------------------------
```

Which can be rendered as like below JSON Format. Lets keep this as first format.

```
{
  "children": [{
    "id": 100,
    "title": "Asia",
    "parentId": ""
  }, {
    "id": 107,
    "title": "India",
    "parentId": 100
  }, {
    "id": 108,
    "title": "Tamil Nadu",
    "parentId": 107
  }, {
    "id": 109,
    "title": "Karnataka",
    "parentId": 107
  }, {
    "id": 112,
    "title": "Chennai",
    "parentId": 108
  }, {
    "id": 113,
    "title": "Bengalaru",
    "parentId": 109
  }]
}
```

I would like to have below JSON Format which is good for recursive drill down menu and keep this as second format.

```
{
  "children": [{
    "id": 100,
    "title": "Asia",
    "children": [{
      "title": "India",
      "children": [{
        "title": "Tamil Nadu",
        "children":[{
          "title": "Chennai"
        }]
      }, {
        "title": "Karnataka",
        "children":[{
          "title": "Bengaluru"
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "title": "China"
    }]
  }]
}
```

My question here which format is REST Standard / best practice in REST. Using first format and modifying through JavaScript model / using second format.

Answer (score 5):

**Neither Format Is REST Standard.**

- REST does not define representation standards.
- REST does not specify the format of resources.
- REST is an "architectural style" not a standard. [Fielding Dissertation - The Original Document Describing REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2)

It is your application's decision whether to use a hierarchical representation or a flat representation, or to offer both, just as it is your decision whether to use JSON or XML or Protocol Buffers or HTML, or all of them, for example.

**Neither Representation Is Best Practice.**

It depends on your applications' needs or your clients' needs.

There really is no one size fits all best practice for this. You will find a range of opinions. There are potentially great reasons to do it either way, depending on your requirements, tools, team proficiencies, etc.

You really just have to consider the pros and cons in your situation, and don't worry about it too much. Either choice will work with most tools.

**REST Questions You Should Ask**

1. What are these resources? What will the resource identifiers look like? (URI's) A simple, efficient, appropriately cacheable URI model is at the heart or foundation of a good REST service. How will a client specify what media type, representation it wants?
2. Will you need to retrieve more detail on the individual states (of India) and capitals? Is this a collection and are those states individual resources?
3. If the application will need to GET or PUT, say "Karnataka" how will it know what URI to use? That is not included in your representation.
4. If this is not a read only resource, how will use use the HTTP commands (GET, PUT, POST, etc.) to act on it? Using those commands properly is at the heart of REST over HTTP.
5. After that, look up HATEOAS. Then have another coffee. Read it again, then post questions here if needed. Seriously HATEOAS seems to throw people for a loop.
6. Now you are ready for the versioning wars. How will you evolve your api? Will you version it? (The REST thought police will get me for even asking that question.)

**There's No Law That Says Good APIs Have To Use The REST Style**
Fielding is happy to remind us of this, if we need a respected voice.

Really doing REST is a commitment to some intellectual effort, and some discipline in designing, testing and evolving your API. It's not needed for every API.

Sometimes you just have to build stuff that works and ship it. Refactor on the next iteration when you know more.